# Am I understanding the scattering amplitude correctly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, scattering, probability

Suppose we have a particle, which is described by the wave function Ψ1, which hits another particle. In the final state, we get a superposition of an incident plane wave Ψ1 and a scattered spherical wave Ψ2? And depending on the amplitude Ψ2, you can get the probability that the device will register the interaction?
[image]

Comment: afaik a plane wave cannot be the wavefunction of a particle as the probability of a plane wave cannot be defined,  its defintion is up to infinity and cannot be normalized. I guess of a spherical wave too. Wave packets are needed, but I think with quantum field theory this can happen by using creation and annihilaton operators on the corresponding quantum fields.

Comment: @annav It’s more about something else. There is an incident particle, the wave function of which describes the initial state. After scattering, a superposition of the incident and scattered particles is obtained, or is only the scattered one left?

Comment: The way you state it it is an interaction of two incoming particles ( no matter one is at rest) which will be outgoing after scattering.

Comment: @annav There will also be two particles at the exit, but the scattered particle will be in a state of superposition, consisting of a scattered and non-scattered components?

Comment: No. Wavefunctions work ok with bound states, and are solutions of qm equations with specific potentials. Scatterings cannot be described by simple solutions , that is why the scattering matrix formalism was developed see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix

Comment: In what sense no? Why doesn't superposition work? I know what a scattering matrix is, it takes into account all possible amplitudes at the output, including the amplitude of no scattering.

Comment: The plane wave and radial wave functions you imagine cannot describe the probability ( $Ψ^*Ψ$ ) of finding the particle at (x,y,z,t) it is infinitessimally close to zero for each particle. One needs the formalism of QFT with creation and annihilation differential operators operating on the fields ( which are plane waves) to have a correct mathematical model.

Comment: @annav However, the scattering matrix also takes into account the amplitude corresponding to the case without scattering. That is, it is a superposition with all possible S_fi.